# Action no longer being found within lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, forgot-your-password

I'm working in salesforce communities right now and making some edits to components. Specifically the forgot password component. I haven't touched the controller or helper, just adding some wording and changing styles within the lightning component. All of a sudden, I'm getting the error

**Unable to find 'forgotPassowrd' on 'compound://c.forgotPassword'**

From what I can tell, this is from the following line in the helper:

```
var action = component.get("c.forgotPassowrd");
```

There was no issue with this, even after I started adding elements and styles within the component. I can't narrow down what I might have done to all of a sudden make this not work. The controller within the component is still **LightningForgotPasswordController** and I haven't gotten rid of any of the aura attributes or anything like that. Any help or a direction to start looking would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you have any js controller function with name forgotPassowrd

Comment: Can you please share the code

Comment: Manjot Singh - It's just the default controller and helper from the forgotPassword component. I haven't changed anything, so there's a handleForgotPassword, but no straight forgotPassword.

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled forgotPassword as forgotPassowrd. Because the javascript controller text does not match the apex controller method name, you receive the error.

Comment: It seems like when you edit a built in lightning component, the copy that it lets you edit is littered with errors. After realizing that this was the problem I also noticed that by default all instances of 'helper' are spelled 'helpler' as well as some other places in the controller and helper that have switched around letters.

Comment: That's unfortunate :(